# How to insert a blank page or other annotation space next to each page

Tags: page-breaking, blank-page

For a questionaire-alike document, I want to add a blank page next to every other page. These pages must get the default headers, footers etceteras and should be included in the page numbering. This leaves the reader with space to make notations or answer some of the questions posed in the document.

I can add a `twoside` to documentclass and then manually add a `\newpage` on several places, but that seems like the wrong approach to me.

Since I am really new to (La)Tex, I might be going at this in the entirely wrong angle. Should I use some "annotatable" documentclass instead? I.e. one that adds a large margin for notes? Is there another way to solve this even better, maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code does what you need. It uses the package `everyshi`. You can as well put any content on the empty page. Package `lipsum` is loaded to provide some dummy text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% THIS IS THE CODE YOU NEED
\makeatletter
\usepackage{everyshi}
\EveryShipout{%
\ifodd\c@page\relax%
\vbox{%
%INSERT ANY CONTENT HERE
}%
\newpage%
\fi%
}
\makeatother
% END OF THE CODE

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this is a solution that adds a new page after every "other" page with unchanged header and whatsoever. LaTeX can do nearly anything. Of course, you can make large margins if that's enough, you can shorten the page so that there's a lot of space in the bottom (both can be easily done with the package [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry).